# JL after test in assembly

Tags: assembly

I see the following code -

```
add    $0x14,%esp
mov    %eax,%ebx
test   %ebx,%ebx
jl     80590d7 <XXXX+0xbc7>
```

I am having confusion in undesrtanding the above code. If we are having instruction like test %ebx, %ebx should it always be equal?

Also, i ran in GDB and following is the output from info registers -

```
(gdb) info registers
eax            0x0      0
ecx            0x189f   6303
edx            0x6      6
ebx            0x442ff4 4468724
esp            0xffbde13c       0xffbde13c
ebp            0xffbde4c8       0xffbde4c8
esi            0x1d5c4d50       492588368
edi            0x444140 4473152
eip            0x80590dd        0x80590dd
eflags         0x296    [ PF AF SF IF ]
cs             0x23     35
ss             0x2b     43
ds             0x2b     43
es             0x2b     43
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x63     99
```

Can someone please explain how does this work?

Comment: `jl` has little to do with "equal". It just tests whether SF != OF. `test` sets OF to false and SF to the sign of `operand1 & operand2`, so in effect it's going to take the jump if `ebx` was negative. I don't know why they didn't just write `js`. That would make more sense.

Comment: Well the code above is a disassembled code from icc compiler.

Comment: Ok, but I still can't think of any reason for this. It doesn't even help macro-op fusion - a `js` can also fuse with a `test`, same as `jl`.

Answer (score 2):

It's an odd way of testing the Sign flag. The JL instruction is designed to test if the (subtraction in) a CMP instruction resulted in a negative value.

However, a TEST instruction seems to set the SF flag as well if the result has the sign bit set.

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TEST_(x86_instruction)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TEST_%28x86_instruction%29)

Comment: Well the code above is a disassembled code from icc compiler.